# How to avoid repetition when calling async request?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I´m using Vue 2.6.10 and Vuesax 3 to build an application.

This app makes a lot of async like this:

```
 async listResource() {
  this.$vs.loading(); //Start of the loading
  try {
    const response = await repository.get();
    this.list = response.data;
    this.$vs.notify({ title: "Success", text: "List fetched." });
    this.sdoSmething();
  } catch (err) {
    this.$vs.notify({
      title: err, //I´m not showing this error to the user, this is just to exemplify
      text: "There was an error when fetching the resource"
    });
  }
  finally{
    this.$vs.loading.close(); //Close the loading
  }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I´m repeating a lot of code over and over.

If I need to make another request, I´ll have to create another method, send a specific message if the promisses resolves or if it fails...

How would be a nice way to abstract this?

Comment: It depends on your particular use case and what needs to be shared. Its hard to provide a more generic abstraction without this information.

Comment: I will have many similar blocks like these, the difference between each one is regarding the text of the message and the repository that is beeing called.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `listResource` method parameters to change the messages. For example two callback functions that will return a message, static or based on the input of those callbacks.

In the example below I've written two functions which will build a message object. The `successMessage` is static and the `errorMessage` takes in the error from the `catch` statement.

Both are passed to the `listResource` method in the order of the parameters and called whenever the request succeeded or failed.

```
class YourClass {

  async listResource(success, error) {
    this.$vs.loading(); //Start of the loading
    try {
      const response = await repository.get();
      this.list = response.data;
      this.$vs.notify(success());
      this.sdoSmething();
    } catch (err) {
      this.$vs.notify(error(err)); // Pass the message.
    } finally {
      this.$vs.loading.close(); //Close the loading
    }
  };

}

const successMessage = () => ({ 
  title: "Success", 
  text: "List fetched." 
});

const errorMessage = err => ({
  title: err,
  text: "There was an error when fetching the resource"
});

const instance = new YourClass();
instance.listResource(successMessage, errorMessage);

// Or inside the instance.
await this.listResource(successMessage, errorMessage);
```